# MonocularCalibration hanging

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to use the MonocularCalibration node for calibrating my ueye camera. The program seems to be working fine meaning it is displaying a nice image with identified corners and lines and I can see that it is trying to adjust the corners and lines. The documentation says that when the CALIBRATE button lights up click on it to complete the calibration. But when the button lighten up and I clicked on it nothing happened and the node hanged.

I have a node which is publishing just the image data as sensor_msgs/Image on a topic "img_out" and I am using this topic to run the MonocularCalibration node.

Do I have to publish the camera_info as well ? It doesnt say so in the tutorial of MonocularCalibration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11328/monocularcalibration-hanging/) by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on 2011-09-28**:
I tried to run it again and this time it showed me some progress by activating the other two buttons as well named "Save" and "Commit". But it is not showing me the calibration results. How can I publish the sensor_msgs/CameraInfo ? I think I have missed this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like it's working now that you have the save and commit buttons enabled.  I believe it saves to file, and does not publish.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1